# unfold children without their bodies

Tags: org-mode

When the cursor is on the 'heading 1' and I press TAB, it's unfolding the checklist with children (ex.1).

I would like to see only the 'chores' without its children - 'gym,cleanup,work'.(ex.2).

```
ex.1
* heading 1
  - [0%] chores
    - [ ] gym
    - [ ] cleanup
    - [ ] work
** subheading

ex.2   
* heading 1
 - [0%] chores...
** subheading
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for text: just paste your Org mode file as text between triple backticks. That way, I can cut and paste exactly what you have to test it. With images, I have to retype everything.

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: I have tried various things without complete success. The closest is: TAB on `heading 1`, then TAB on the `chores` line to close the list underneath it. I don't think there is a way to get what you want by default. You can of course write a function (or macro) to do the above but that assumes a fixed structure, with a headline, a first level list directly underneath and a second level list under that. Even with that, the behavior is stateful and somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html

`C-c TAB` (outline-show-children)

Expose all direct children of the subtree. With a numeric prefix argument N, expose all children down to level N.

Comment: nope, it will show only heading 1 & subheading 1 - without 'chores' checklist

Answer (score 0):

```
* heading 1
  - [0%] chores
  :PROPERTIES:
  - [ ] gym
  - [ ] cleanup
  - [ ] work
  :END:
** subheading
```

I tried with :PROPERTIES:
It works the way I wanted. Don't unfold children as default.
But the lower checklist is disconnected with main checklist item.
I know it's not the right answer & solution but kind of works.
And maybe that would be a direction to go? Create something like :MORE: ?